# unable to delete custom plugin from datafusion instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I tried uploading a custom jar as cdap plugin and it has few errors in it. I want to delete that particular plugin and upload a new one. what is the process for it ? I tried looking for documentation and it was not much informative.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on the hamburger menu, and click on Control Center at the bottom of the left panel. In the Control Center, click on Filter by, and select the checkbox for Artifacts. After that, you should see the artifact being listed in the Control Center, which then you can delete.

Alternatively, we suggest that while developing, the version of the artifact should be suffixed with -SNAPSHOT (ie. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT). Any -SNAPSHOT version can be overwritten simply by reuploading. This way, you don't have to delete first before deploying a patched plugin JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Actually each Data Fusion instance is running in GCP [tenant project](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/glossary#tenant) inside fully isolated area, keeping all orchestration actions, pipeline lifecycle management tasks and coordination as a part of GCP managed scenarios, thus you can make a user defined actions within a dedicated Data Fusion UI or targeting execution environment via CDAP [*REST API*](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.6.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/index.html) HTTP calls.

The purpose for using Data Fusion UI is to create a visual design for data pipelines, controlling ETL data processing through different phases of data executions, therefore you can do the same accessing particular CDAP API inventory.

Looking into the origin CDAP documentation you can find [Artifact HTTP RESTful API](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.6.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/artifact.html) that offers a set of HTTP methods that you can consider to manage custom plugin operations.

Referencing GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference), there are a few simple steps how to prepare sufficient environment, supplying `INSTANCE_URL` variable for the target Data Fusion instance in order to smoothly trigger API functions within HTTP call methods against CDAP endpoint, i.e.:

```
export INSTANCE_ID=your-instance-id
export CDAP_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe \
--location=us-central1 \
--format="value(apiEndpoint)" \
${INSTANCE_ID})
```

When you are ready with above steps, you can push a particular HTTP call method, approaching specific action.

For plugin [deletion](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.6.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/artifact.html#delete-a-system-artifact), try this one, invoking HTTP **DELETE** method:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/system/artifacts/<artifact-name>/versions/<artifact-version>"
```

Comment: New link to Artifact API docs: https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477692148/Artifact+Microservices